# Opencv Images Orthorectification

Tags: c++, opencv, orthographic, image-stitching

I'm writing a program in opencv that stitches aerial images taken by a drone. The problem is that the stitch,after a certain point, start to "curving", so  my homography matrix will be messed up and I can't stitch anything more.
There's a way in openv to do images orthorectivication without gps or DEM parameters? If not in opencv, there's a library easily integrable with opencv?

Thanks!
PS: I'm programming in C++

Comment: use bundle adjustment or search literature for different methods to reduce drift

Comment: I've done a search for the bundle adjustment, and I think it isn't very clear.. I'm implementing manually the stitching pipeline but I can't pass my feature vector (calculated with orb) in the bundle adjustment function. There's a good tutorial for opencv bundle adjustment?

Comment: maybe you have to implement bundle adjustment yourself

Comment: there's a paper or some pseudocode I can refer to?